Iterating over a JSON object
My PS skill are rusty at best. But being faced with users in an AD PS seems to be the tool to use.
I need to update some user properties in our AD. To do this, I created a JSON file (something like this):
{
   "xyz" : {
      "title" : "Leerling Copernicus SG, klas: 2MH1A",
      "displayName" : "Student xyz",
      "surname" : "xyz"
   },
   "abc" : {
      "displayName" : "Student abc",
      "givenname" : "Student"
   }
}

There are in fact 4000+ users and the properties to change vary from user to user.
Some googling learned me I could make a PS object out of that file by doing
$json = Get-Content -Path 'C:\somewhere\mutaties.json' -Raw|ConvertFrom-Json

after that I expected I could iterate over the object like
foreach ($user in $json) {
  foreach ($property in $user) {
    // do something smart
  }
}

But this does not work at all. At the first iteration $user seems to contain the complete object.
Furthermore: how do I access the account keys like xyz and abc, and the property names?
Edit: this it what I came up with:
$jsonObject = Get-Content -Path 'C:\somewhere\mutaties.json' -Raw|ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($user in $jsonObject.psobject.Properties) {
    $key =  $user.name
    $properties = $user.VALUE
    write-host $key

    foreach ($property in $properties.psobject.Properties) {
        $name = $property.Name
        $value = $property.VALUE
        write-host `t $name`t $value
    }
}

Not as sophisticated as the answer, but it did the trick for me

This question is similar to: How to iterate json object in powershell. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You could change the the json format where you have an array of a property called 'user'.

Because the Json you have is a single object, you will need to do enumeration on the object properties, for that you can access the .PSObject.Properties. Example of how you can approach your code:
foreach ($user in $json.PSObject.Properties) {
    $properties = @{}
    foreach ($property in $user.Value.PSObject.Properties) {
        $properties[$property.Name] = $property.Value
    }

    @{
        user       = $user.Name
        properties = $properties
    }
}

# Name                           Value
# ----                           -----
# properties                     {[surname, xyz], [displayName, Student xyz], [title, Leerling Copernicus SG, klas: 2MH1A]}
# user                           xyz
# properties                     {[givenname, Student], [displayName, Student abc]}
# user                           abc


Someone suggested another thread which resulted in something simular:
